# Passing Numeric Value to Variable with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Hey guys I have the following controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.landing')
    .controller('LandingController', LandingController);

    function LandingController($http) {

      var vm = this;
      vm.quantity = 9;
      $http.get('api/getarticles').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      vm.articles = data;
      });
      $http.get('api/getFeaturedArticles').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      vm.featuredArticles = data;
      });
      }
})();
```

And on my view I have this button

```
<button ng-click="vm.quantity + 3">Add</button>
```

I am trying to get the button on my view to add a numeric value of 3 to my `vm.quantity` variable within my controller.

However If I press the button on the front end the value of 3 isn't added to the `vm.quantity` variable.

Any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Why not you are calling one function on ng-click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable is not changed as when you do vm.quantity + 3, the result is not stored anywhere ... you should do :

```
<button ng-click="vm.quantity = vm.quantity + 3">Add</button>
```

Or

```
<button ng-click="addValue(3)">Add</button>
```

where in your controller :

```
$scope.addValue = function(value) {
    vm.quantity += value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try 2 things : either do something like {{vm.quantity + 3}} so that Angular will evaluate that expression (right now you're missing curly braces) or second : add to ng-click a function something like increment and in the controller do the actual increasing.

Hope it helps

Comment: angular already evaluate the expression as it is written in a Angular directive (ng-click) , curly braces are only needed in standard HTML attributes.

Comment: no problem ;) I was using it intensively last months so I remember few things